# How to extract formatted text from html and also display it back with same format as before

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am Trying to build Note taking app. How can I save text with same formatting as I type in html element in database and also show that text back from database to user with same formatting as it was. I have enabled `contenteditable` aatribute on `<p>` tag. I am extracting value form p tag and save to database and vice versa. but I am not able to persist format as users typed.

ex.

```
<p contenteditable="true">
   jsdkn insd insddd
nsdns msdkm psd,d km

   kndknd kmksd kmdd
</p>
```

i want to save above text in same format to database and retrieve it back with same formatting.

also id it ok to enable `contenteditable`?

Comment: How are you saving that in the database and how is it different from your format?

Comment: @LajosArpad I am taking values from <p/> tag and directly saving it to database.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on that if you would like to increase your chances to get help. I cannot find the error in a code that was not shared.